# Run simple C/C++ examples for gphoto2

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, libgphoto2

I would like to use the library gphoto2 to control my canon camera (take images, change settings etc).  I have the gphoto library installed on my library using apt-get on Ubuntu and I have the basic command line commands working.  I want to now use C/C++ code to access gphoto2.  Can I do that with the version I have installed using apt-get or do I need to download some bindings?  Can anyone give me some example code?